# How can I get an Account object from its id?

Tags: apex, javascript, account, query, id

I have a button calling a javascript function on an opportunity object that passes its associated account's id to an apex function.  What is the best way in apex to retrieve that Account object?  I want to send it to an external web service.
Currently 
JS:

```
{!requireScript("/soap/ajax/20.0/connection.js")} 
{!requireScript("/soap/ajax/20.0/apex.js")} 
var idd = '{!Opportunity.AccountId}';
retStr = sforce.apex.execute("ParseManager", "sendAccountToParse", {a:id});
alert(retStr);
```

apex function in ParseManager Class:

```
webservice static String sendAccountToParseS(String a){

        // retrieve account object from id
        // retrieve relevant properties from account object
        // send to external web service (I know how to do this)
        // HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);

        String confirmationString = "";

        return confirmationString;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

First, change what you're passing as your variables are different:

`retStr = sforce.apex.execute("ParseManager", "sendAccountToParse", {a:idd}); // idd instead of id`

Then since you've got the Account Id passed into your Apex method, you can simply write a SOQL query to retrieve all related data for the account:

```
webservice static String sendAccountToParseS(String a)
{
    List <Account> accounts = [SELECT Id, Name, Owner.Name, Phone, Type, ANYTHING_ELSE FROM Account WHERE Id = :a];

    if (accounts.isEmpty() == false)
    {
        // we've got a matching account
        Account account = accounts[0];

        // The account variable now holds all info that was in the query above
        // you can serialize it before sending as well
        // String jsonBody = JSON.serialize(account);
        // send the request
    }
    else
    {
        // handle error when there is no matching account for X reason
    }

    String confirmationString = "";

    return confirmationString;
}
```

Comment: Thank you!!!  I made a typo on the first part copying my code over, both parts were id.  I was unsure if I needed to do a SOQL query or if there was a better approach.  This is exactly what I needed, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can skip the Apex Code altogether if you want, and send it through JavaScript directly.

Start with the AJAX Toolkit:

```
{!RequireScript("/soap/ajax/34.0/connection.js")}
sforce.connection.sessionId = "{!$Api.Session_ID}";
```

Next, get the account:

```
var account = sforce.connection.retrieve("Field1,Field2...", "Account", ["{!Opportunity.AccountId}"]);
```

Finally, send it through the built-in JavaScript proxy:

```
sforce.connection.remoteFunction(
{ url: "some-endpoint", requestHeaders: {...}, method: "GET", 
 onSuccess: function(response) { ... }
 onFailure: fucntion(response) { ... }
);
```

If you'd rather not do that, you can still send it through Apex Code. Which leads you back to your original question of querying an account.

```
Account record = [SELECT Name, Industry, AccountNumber... FROM Account WHERE Id = :a];
```

Notice that both cases suggest you already know which fields you want. If you don't, you'll need to do a describe beforehand. See [SObjectType](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Schema_SObjectType.htm) methods or [sforce.connection.describeSObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.ajax.meta/ajax/sforce_api_ajax_more_samples.htm).